# Trouble creating VDI's in xenserver

Tags: xenserver, citrix, vdi

Xenserver running on an HP ML350 G5.  Raid5 with 5x2tb  drives plus hot spare.

Local storage is there showing usable 7.5 tb.

Under xencenter I went to local storage, storage, virtual disks.  I created 3 test disks.

The disks show up there but I'm not able to do anything with them.

If I do a cat /proc/partitions they dont show up.  If I do a fdisk -l they don't show up.

All fdisk shows is /dev/cciss/c0d0 which is the full 8tb. 
THen /dev/cciss/c0d0p1 gpt

I'm not sure if I'm missing something really simple here.  The idea here is to create the vdi's so that Openfiler can use them.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do with them? Is the open filer running as a VM on this xen server?

Comment: boburob2 Yes, openfiler is running as a vm. Its running on a 5g vdi on the local storage.  All I want to do is make the rest of that local storage available to openfiler. At this point im just plain confused about how to go about that. I assumed it was just make a new physical disk, actuallly 3 due to the 2tb limit, and then give the Openfiler vm access to them.  I must be missing something because openfiler cannot see them.

Comment: Yes, you need to attach the disks to the VM for the VM to see it. If you select the VM and select the Storage tab. In the open screen you either select Add... to create brand new disks or Attach.. (which sounds like the correct option for you), to add pre created disks. Then, if you have not got the xen server tools installed, you may need to restart the VM for it to pick up the disks.

Comment: That's what I thought. I did that. Under that VM, under storage, virtual disks I have the Test1 disk there.  It's showing Active=no, and no device path.   Activate is greyed out.  I'm going to assume that's why it's not showing up for the VM to use.

Comment: Yup, just shut down the VM and turn it back on.

Comment: boburob I swear I restarted that vm multiple times and it never showed up.  Does it have to be "shut down" actually, I was just restarting it.

Comment: Yeah, if you havent got the xen server tools installed it needs to be completely turned off, not just restarted! Ive run into the same problem a number of times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be that Openfiler did not have the xenserver linux tools installed onto it. This meant that when you just rebooted the VM, the disks where not attached.

Turning off the VM and then starting it again fixed the issue!

Comment: Well no actually.   I'm still trying to get tools installed.  Seems there is no easy way to install.  That's the next issue since without it I cannot attach more than 3 vdi's.

Comment: http://www.juggled.co.uk/archive/latest/xstools4openfiler.html

Comment: That is the exact walkthrough I used.   Actually to tie this thread up.  Long story short I spent hours trying to get xentools working under OF 2.99.  No luck.  Finally gave up.  Frankly at this point I don't think 2.99 is ready for use under xen. Multiple dependency issues with conary, rpms' that install but still no PV. Maybe they will release an actual appliance in the next version.